# Handling output of the flip-flop operator

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I've been strugling with the flip-flop operator in order to replace a particular value in a input xml file.

The file structure is as follows:

```
<a>BLE</a>
<-- hur dur -->
<b>12345</b>
<-- hur der -->
<c>VER1.2.3</c>
<-- hur dest -->
<d>VER1.2.3</d>

<a>CLE</a>
<-- hur dur -->
<b>12345</b>
<-- hur der -->
<c>VERX'.Y'.Z'</c>
<-- hur dest -->
<d>VERX'.Y'.Z'</d>

<a>DLE</a>
<-- hur dur -->
<b>12345</b>
<-- hur der -->
<c>VERX".Y".Z"</c>
<-- hur dest -->
<d>VERX".Y".Z"</d>
etc ...
```

So lets say I want to change the version field (d and c) of any particular variable. For brevity sake let it be BLE. I have to first find the block with the values of BLE (lines 1-7) and then replace fields  and  with the new value.

I've been trying different stuff, like:

```
perl -pi.bak -ne 'if ( /BLE/ .. /<\/d/ ){ s/VER[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[A-Z][[:digit:]]\+[A-Z]\?/$ver/}' dur.xml
```

or

```
perl -ne "print if ( /BLE/ .. /<\/d>/ ) " dur.xml | sed "/VER[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+[A-Z]\?/$ver/"
```

where $ver is a set variable (ver="VERX.Y.Z"). However the first one doesn't do anything to the input file (I'd prefer to do it in-place); the second produces more or less what I want but the output is limited to the BLE block:

```
<a>BLE</a>
<-- hur dur -->
<b>12345</b>
<-- hur der -->
<c>VERX.Y.Z</c>
<-- hur dest -->
<d>VERX.Y.Z</d>
```

but that this output can't be easily redirected to a file with > because it drops everything else besides BLE.

Is there any way one can modify the original file in a similar fashion as the one described above?

Thanks a bunch,
drinker

Comment: Is that input supposed to be real XML? It doesn't look like it. Please include an _exact_ file.

Comment: ...also, here isn't any `buildversion` string in your example data...

Comment: @simbabque No it's not really a XML - the file I'm editing just has a .xml extension- but the structure is kinda similar. Also the original looks exactly like this only the tags a,b,c and d have different names

Comment: @jm666 Oops, copy-paste fail. Fixed

Comment: So the file has blocks of tags, and empty lines, and those not-comments `<-- ... -->`? And you only want to change the `<d>` where `<a>` has `BLE`?

Comment: Yes, empty lines once in a while, tag blocks, the "<-- stuff -->" has no real purpose (could be considered a comment) but it's always squeezed between each tag line. And yes, I want to change `<d>` but also `<c>` (same value as `<d>`) for `<a> = BLE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do the task as I see it

```
perl -pe's{<d>VER\K.*?(</d>)}{xxx$1} if m{BLE} .. m{</d>}' data.txt
```

This replaces whatever is between `<d>VER` and (first) `</d>` with `xxx`, on the lines in the given range. The [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) is the form of the [positive lookbehind](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) which discards matches prior to it so we don't have to capture them and put them back in.

The `-p` prints `$_` every time, while `s{}{}` changes it, so you get all lines printed, changed or not. It servers no purpose having both it and `-n` (same but doesn't print) but if you do then `-p` overrides the other. To have the file changed *in-place* with a backup indeed add `-i.bak`.  See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

If you need to access specific numbers you can instead use regex

```
s{<d>VER\K(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)</d>}{$1.$new.$3</d>}
```

In order to allow for an optional letter following a number, what your code hints at, use `(\d+[A-Z]?)`. If `'` and `"` in `X'` and `X"` are actual characters please adjust this (the first example is fine). If you meant to use them as "X-prime" (and double-prime), don't -- it is very misleading here.

For more flexibility convert this to a script, which is probably a good idea anyway. You may use variables directly instead of the literals above (`VER` and `xxx`) if this is in a shell script.

---

The problem in the posted code isn't with the "flip-flop" ([range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)), which merely selects lines and which you use correctly.  It is with the regex, in which you have `[A-Z]` before the last number and another one following it.  The data just doesn't have a letter there, so it doesn't match.

Also, note that `\?` turns the [quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) `?` into a literal `?`, which also isn't in the data.

Comment: Thanks @zdim. This worked for me `perl -i.bak -pe "s{<d>\K.*?</d>}{$ver</d>} if m{BLE} .. m{\/d}" dur.xml`